# Creating a reference to variable directly from string (without switch statement)

Tags: php

I know the title is not very clear so here it's in code:

```
function output($selector){
    $one = 1;
    $two = 2;
    $there = 3;

    return ? //should return 1 without if or switch statement
}


echo output('one');
```

If this is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) by prefixing the `$selector` variable with another `$`:

```
return $$selector;
```

Remember to do sanity checks and/or implement default values, so you don't end up generating unnecessary undefined variable errors and such from within your function.

Comment: I was just going to try that but my code editor (notepad++) led me to believe that it would not be right. :)

Comment: @Chad: I know what you mean, but don't worry, it's just a bug with Notepad++'s syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like the idea of using variable variables.

Why not just use an array?

```
function output($selector){
    $choices = array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'there' => 3,
    );

    return $choices[$selector];
}
```

or if your values aren't set in stone:

```
function output($selector){
    // Complex calculations here
    $one = 1;
    $two = 2;
    $there = 3;

    return array(
        'one' => $one,
        'two' => $two,
        'there' => $there,
    )[$selector];
}
```

(Yes, I realize this is pretty similar to using a switch statement)

Answer (score 0):

```
function output($selector){
    $one = 1;
    $two = 2;
    $there = 3;

    return $$selector;
}


echo output('one');
```

But it's not most clever thing.

Comment: "not most clever thing" can you explain why please?

Comment: BoltClock answered more detailed. In addition: IDE will not be able to suggest code completion in this case - typos, errors. Or in variable can be some kind of users input and it will be security issue.